# STL custom allocator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I am trying to use custom allocator for STL. I tried the below sample. It prevents 
assigning `Custom::vector` pointer to `std::vector`. Is there any disadvantage or performance issue in the below way.

```
namespace Custom
{
  template <typename _Tp, typename Allocator = CustomAllocator<_Tp> >
  class vector : private std::vector<_Tp, Allocator >
  {
    using std::vector<_Tp, Allocator>::push_back;
  };
}

int main(void)
{
  Custom::vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Just the use of your custom allocator by default, or are you trying to restrict what methods can be called on `v`?

Comment: We wanted to use customer allocator because we want allocator to uses static memory pool and we wanted to restrict the methods as well. We want few features of vector but use the custom allocator by default for few modules [not global scope].

Comment: Why not simply a type alias `namespace Custom { template <typename T> using vector = std::vector<T, CustomAllocator<T>>; }`?

Comment: Note: the use of `_Tp` as a template parameter name is forbidden (to you casual user), identifiers matching the following regular expressions: `^_[A-Z]\w*` and `\w*__\w*` are reserved to the implementation in ALL scopes, and identifiers matching `^_[a-z]\w*` are reserved to the implementation in the global scope.

Comment: I tried the namespace Custom { template <typename T> using vector = std::vector<T, CustomAllocator<T>>; }. It looks like we need g++ 4.8 version of g++; The compiler we are using is not 4.8 version. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Performance of allocations is obviously depending on the implementation of CustomAllocator.

Answer (score 1):

Given that there is almost no information as of what you are trying to do, where you need to be compatible and where you need not, it is almost impossible to answer the question.

Assuming that the using declarations are in the *visible* (i.e. `public`) section of the derived type, this is a way of narrowing the interface and setting a different allocator. There are different concerns here, one of which is that only within the context of `Custom::vector` or a `friend` the vector can be used as a `std::vector` which means that outer code will not be able to convert `Custom::vector<T>` into `std::vector<T, CustomAllocator<T> >` which might be a good or a bad thing.  If you need external code to be able to use `Custom::vector<T>` as a `std::vector<T, CA<T>>` (by pointer or reference) you could make inheritance public, or otherwise remove the type and just provide a type alias (if the only intention is to default the allocator to something different than `std::allocator<T>`).

Another issue, which is present in the C++ allocator model basically everywhere, is that you no longer have a vocabulary type. Two different instantiations of `std::vector` (or `Custom::vector` that differ only on the allocator are unrelated types and cannot be used interchangeably. You cannot write a function that takes a `std::vector<T>` and call it with `std::vector<T, CA<T>>`.  Again, this might or might not be an issue, and can be worked around by polluting with templates everywhere (either operate in terms of iterators, or else template on the allocator type).

Regarding this last point, there is a proposal to add a polymorphic allocator to the C++ standard, and there is an existing implementation in [BSL](https://github.com/bloomberg/bde). The trade off is paying for an additional dynamic dispatch per allocation and gaining a vocabulary type (code need not be templated, `bsl::vector<T>` is the same type regardless of which allocator is used to pull memory. Whether the cost of the dynamic dispatch is small or large is up for discussion (it is currently being discussed by the committee).  Some initial performance tests seem to indicate that the cost of dynamic dispatch is smallish with the least performing allocators but noticeable with faster (fixed buffer, sequential) allocators. Take this in context for what it means: choosing the correct allocator will give you some gain in the C++ model, and a smaller gain (constant factor) in the BSL allocator model. The constant factor is more noticeable when the cost of allocation is smaller.  The advantage will be that `bsl::vector<T>` is a vocabulary type, a function taking a `bsl::vector<T>` does not care about what allocator is in use, it just *works*.